# Perl 6 support udp protocol from IO::Socket::INET

Tags: sockets, udp, raku

Why does [IO::Socket::INET](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Socket::INET) not support the UDP protocol?

Comment: Can you please reformulate the question? Tell what you have tried, how has it failed, how did you realize it does not support it, what is the use case... Maybe there's an alternative to it. Such as you have formulated it and looking at the documentation, the answer would be quite obvious: the documentation says it supports TCP sockets and that's all they do. This is why make your focus a bit more broad might help you get a good answer.

Comment: in the documentation for this class there are no mention of this protocol

Comment: That is absolutely correct. Only TCP is mentioned. It says "provides TCP sockets". So simple answer it "this is not the class that does this". That is why I ask you to reformulate your question and make it broader, something like "What class should I use for a UDP client/server socket in Perl6?

Comment: http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/intranet/perlbook/cookbook/ch17_06.htm IO::Socket::INET supports the udp in perl5

Comment: That's perl 5. Different language, different decisions... And you see, that kind of rationale could have been inserted in your question. See answers too. I mean, if it's not a problem to you I can edit the question that way.

Answer (score 6):

UDP is supported via [`IO::Socket::Async`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Socket::Async). UDP is connectionless, so this is the natural way to do it.

In *principle*, you could make [`IO::Socket::INET`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Socket::INET) support UDP as well, but that's not necessarily a good idea...

Comment: someone should probably fix the doc page for `IO::Socket::Async`, which is subitled *Asynchronous TCP socket*, omitting a mention of UDP

Comment: in practice socket === connection === Transport Connection Protocol